# android alarm clock app crashes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am trying to make simple alarm app using android studio...I 
     think my code is correct although it crashes.I think the problem is with 
      alarm receiver and service class....i have use if-else to specify if alarm
    is on and ringtone is off or alarm is on or ringtone off and some more....
    please help....thanks

here is the code:

will this do:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lakshya.wakeywakey, PID: 2120
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.lakshya.wakeywakey.RingtonePlayService@4a8166c0 with Intent { cmp=com.example.lakshya.wakeywakey/.RingtonePlayService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2717)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                      at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
                      at com.example.lakshya.wakeywakey.RingtonePlayService.onStartCommand(RingtonePlayService.java:37)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2700)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add stacktrace log, almost impossible to say whats wrong without it

Comment: i have updated the my question by adding the log.....but still no reply from other users......tell me to add anything or delete unnecessary content.....waiting for reply....

Comment: thats because your log doesnt contain **Exception**. Just log shows nothing, we need Exception stacktrace log.

Comment: i have given the exception stack trace.....please see to it..

Comment: indeed, sorry didnt noticed. Answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is inside `onStartCommand` method

I guess on that line, because bundle can be null or doesnt contain string "extra"

```
String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
Log.e("Ringtone extra is" ,state);
```

Just add check for null

```
String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
if (state == null)
   state = "null";
Log.e("Ringtone extra is" ,state);
```

Comment: thanx deadmc....app does not crash but it doesn't work....ringtone does not play on setting alarm.....please see to it too

Comment: @user7786905 does your app run media_song.start();?

Comment: yeah it does@DEADMC

Comment: when i set on the alarm ,the 'extra' sent to receiver and service is null while on switching off it works fine...can u see my alarm clock java classes....i think the problem is with handler.

Comment: I know You have posted the answer to the question but at least help me run the app properly...

Comment: @user7786905 its hard to say where **exactly** your code works not as expected. And there is too much doubtful code, especially I cant understand why dont you use something like EventBus instead of strange handler and multiple bundles.